# Retrieve the total record count of a table in SQLITE3 using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite

For context, I am a newbie to python and in sqlite3 development.

I'd like to retrieve an integer value of the total records of a specific table using the SELECT clause statement in SQLITE3 using python3. How should I proceed in doing this?

My current code is:

```
    with conn:
    c.execute("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM normal_configuration")
    print(c.fetchone())
```

Output:
`(10,)`

I was hoping I could retrieve just the integer but it's returning this. Can someone also explain to me why is this the output of this certain code? I would appreciate all the help and correction. Thank you!

Comment: It’s a tuple. Get the first (and only) value out of the tuple by using indexing.

Comment: Yes it does @mkrieger1 thank you so much for this! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
with conn:
    c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM normal_configuration")
    result = c.fetchone()[0]
    print(result)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I can't believe it's much simple as this. Appreciate it!

Comment: Slow on large db.